# Ler arquivo TXT no Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Tenho uma aplicação em **Ruby on Rails** e preciso ler um determinado arquivo **txt** que será enviado pelo usuário. Após enviar o arquivo, os dados do arquivo serão exibidos para o usuário para que o mesmo confirme se o arquivo está correto, e se sim, em seguida salvá-lo, o arquivo contém letras que são as respostas de uma prova e cada letra representa uma questão, por exemplo:

```
"EEDEBACABDBBADAADEADEAB"
```

ou seja:

```
"1 => E, 2 => E, 3 => D, 4 => E"
```

Esse arquivo será enviado em formato **.txt** através de um formulário, espero que dê pra entender!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você terá que ler caracter por caracter e inserir em um array para depois poder criar o seu hash que auto-incrementa sua `key`.

```
answers = []
array = "abc".each_char.map { |char| char }

array.each_with_index do |value, index|
  answers.push("#{index}" => value)
end

puts answers #[{"0"=>"a"}, {"1"=>"b"}, {"2"=>"c"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respostas = []

File.open("caminho/do/arquivo", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |linha|
    (linha.scan /\w/).each_with_index {|val,i| respostas.push(i => val)}
  end
end
```